# ListView control in MAXScript - Error when pressing escape key with ItemMouseHover event

Tags: maxscript

This problem is associated with the `ItemMouseHover` event handler or other mouse handlers described below. If removed, `ItemMouseHover` (in my case) the problem goes away.

## Update

Here's some very basic code that throws the same error as below.
`MouseMove` event handlier is also added to the culprit list along with `ItemMouseHover` as originally posted.

```
try destroyDialog lvRol catch()

rollout lvRol "MouseMove - Help Required" height:300 width:500
(
  local me = lvRol
  dotNetControl lv "system.windows.forms.listView" height:(me.height) width:(me.width) pos:[0,0]
  on lv MouseMove sender e do print "I like to move it, move it, moooove it!"
  )
createDialog lvRol
```

---

**Here's a gif showing the issue**

[image: JIT issue]

**Here's a link to the error code**

https://pastebin.com/FYZLPWg1

---

I've tried to add the function `_lvIsFormReadyToFocus` but this didn't work.

I've removed this altogether from the full code below and the problem no longer arises.

```
  on lv ItemMouseHover do (
    if _lvIsFormReadyToFocus lv then print "Hovering"
    )
```

---

The problem also happens with other mouse events such as: `MouseMove`, `MouseUp`, `MouseDown`

---

Here's the code and the problem of the code is at line #33.

```
try(destroyDialog lvRol)catch()
clearListener()
rollout lvRol "ItemMouseHover - Help Required" height:300 width:500
(
  -- functions
  local _lvInit, _lvPopulateList, _lvAddColumns, _lvIsFormReadyToFocus
  dotNetControl lv "system.windows.forms.listView" height:(lvRol.height) width:(lvRol.width-1) pos:[0,0]
  fn _lvInit lvArg = (
    lvArg.view          = (dotNetClass "system.windows.forms.view").details
    lvArg.FullRowSelect = true
    lvArg.MultiSelect   = true
    )
  fn _lvPopulateList lvArg = (
    rows = #()
    for x in objects do (
      li = dotNetObject "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem" x.name
      li.tag = dotnetmxsvalue x
      li.subitems.add ((classOf x) as string)
      li.subitems.add (((x.wireColor) as point3) as string)
      append rows li
      )
    lvArg.items.addRange rows
    )
  fn _lvAddColumns lvArg columnsAr = (
    w = (lvArg.width/columnsAr.count)-1
    for x in columnsAr do  (
      lvArg.columns.add x w
      )
    )
  fn _lvIsFormReadyToFocus form = (if form.CanSelect and form.CanFocus and form.Focused then return true else return false)
/*

  HELP REQUIRED HERE for ItemMouseHover

  This throws an error after I press ESC when no items are selected, I get a JIT error.
  Steps to reproduce:
  1. Add a few objects to a scene for this to show any items in the list.
  2. Run this script.
  3. Hold Control key and left click and drag to select.
  4. Hold Alt key and left-click and drag to de-select.
  5. Deselect any items.
  6. Once there are no items selected press ESC a few times until the error occurs.

  */
  on lv ItemMouseHover do (
    if _lvIsFormReadyToFocus lv then print "Hovering"
    )
  on lvRol open do
  (
    _lvInit lv
    _lvAddColumns lv #("Object", "Class", "Wire Color")
    _lvPopulateList lv
    )
  )
createDialog lvRol --pos:[1240,600]
```